# Extract dates in rows of panda dataframe when column value below certain range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a panda dataframe `df` with the contents below;

```
       Date       Factor    Expiry         Grade  
0 12/31/1991    2.138766   3/30/1992      -3.33% 
1 10/29/1992    2.031381    2/8/1993      -1.06% 
2  5/20/1993    2.075670    6/4/1993      -6.38% 
3 10/11/1994    1.441644  11/22/1994      -7.80% 
4  1/11/1995    1.669600   1/20/1995      -7.39% 
5  5/15/1995    1.655237    8/8/1995      -8.68% 
6 10/17/1996    0.942000  10/22/1996      -7.39% 
7  2/19/1998    0.838838   5/26/1998      13.19% 
8   7/9/1998    1.303637   8/28/1998      -6.73% 
9 12/29/1998    1.517232   1/21/1999     -11.03% 
10 4/26/1999    1.613346   5/24/1999      -7.55% 
11  7/8/1999    2.136339   9/23/1999       5.43% 
12 3/22/2000    5.097782   3/29/2000      -6.44%
```

I would like to extract out dates under the `Date` column corresponding to the row with `Grade`  <=-8%.

The desirable output will be a list of string like this;

```
output_dates = ['5/15/1995', '12/29/1998']
```

I am using python v3.6

Comment: @Maria, grades are string type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) for remove last `%`, convert to float and comapre by `le` (`<=`) for boolean mask, filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[df['Grade'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float).le(-8), 'Date']
print (out)
5     5/15/1995
9    12/29/1998
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Or for list:

```
out = df.loc[df.Grade.str.rstrip('%').astype(float).le(-8), 'Date'].tolist()
print (out)
['5/15/1995', '12/29/1998']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [464]: df.loc[df.Grade.str[:-1].astype(float).lt(-8), 'Date']
Out[464]:
5     5/15/1995
9    12/29/1998
Name: Date, dtype: object

In [465]: df.loc[df.Grade.str[:-1].astype(float).lt(-8), 'Date'].tolist()
Out[465]: ['5/15/1995', '12/29/1998']
```

Or, use

```
df.Grade.str.replace('%', '').astype(float)
```